# Is there a GTK media player that can synchronize ID3 tags with directory structure?

Tags: software-recommendation, gtk, music, music-player, id3

I'm looking for a **GTK** media player which will keep the ID3 tags of my tracks synchronised with my library directory structure. That is, when I change the artist tag of a track from X to Y I'd like the track to be moved automatically from ~/Music/X to ~/Music/Y.

Obviously it would be nice if it loaded pretty quickly and was pretty light.

Does such a thing exist? Thanks!

Comment: I don;t think it exists... but you can code the last requirement... :-)

Comment: Exfalso which is the tag editor included in Quodlibet (music player) can move files according to tags, eg `/music/artist/album/tracknumber - title`, but not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for a music player, but for a ID3 tag editor. **EasyTag** doesn't have the best interface in the world, but is very powerful and solve all of my problems.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try rhythmbox. ( http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/)